# A query regarding the effect of Earth's magnetic field on cesium atomic clocks onbard GPS satellites

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, atomic-physics

Is there anyone on here who can tell me how much the variation in magnetic field between ground level and GPS satellite level would effect the frequency of the Caesium atomic clock onboard a GPS satellite? I have a relativity denier who is giving me grief that it is magnetism and not special and general relativity that causes the 49us per day time difference between ground and GPS level. I can easily to the relativity calculations. But calculating the effect of magnetism requires the Zeeman effect and that is a rather more difficult field.

So how much does the magnetic field variation change the frequency of the Caesium clock?

Comment: Are the clocks not magnetically shielded? You can find data on the Earth's magnetic field strength [here](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml).

Comment: This implies that there are corrections  to GPS signal due to magnetic field orientation https://www.sciencealert.com/navigation-systems-finally-caught-up-with-the-mysteriously-north-pole-shift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this:

[Chinese team runs cold atomic clock in space for 15 months](https://phys.org/news/2018-07-chinese-team-cold-atomic-clock.html)

by searching for "mu metal and satellite". [Mu metal shields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal) detectors from magnetic fields for experiments.

In the article:

> The clock used by the team was encased in three layers of mu-metal and was held at a pressure of $10^{-12}$ atmospheres.

In my opinion I expect the normal GPS clocks will also have taken this precaution, so the earth's, or even any stray , magnetic field will not affect the clock frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

External magnetic fields, generally speaking, are death to atomic clocks. This is precisely because the Zeeman shift they induce tends to mess with the clock, but it's not the *average* value of the magnetic field that's all that damaging (since you can measure the field and correct for the shift) but the magnetic field *fluctuations* that are really harmful.

- Magnetic noise along the axis of quantization of the states you're using causes uncontrolled drift in the time you're measuring.
- Magnetic noise *orthogonal* to that axis causes decoherence between the clock starts, which directly degrades the superposition and limits your ability to use it as a clock.

Both of those are terrible (though the latter is definitely worse), and the pervasive nature of magnetic fields, which makes them difficult to shield against, means that magnetic fluctuations are very often one of the main contributions to the error budget of precision metrology using cold atoms. Shielding against them is one of the main design goals, particularly for devices that operate in the 'field' (or, in this case, space).

---

> I have a relativity denier who is giving me grief that...

Frankly: **ignore it**. These arguments do not come in good faith, and they are rarely resolved by additional scientific argumentation. This person has already shown that they're ready to disregard huge chunks of the scientific consensus because of personal reasons that have nothing to do with science; adding more chips and pieces of the scientific consensus to the table won't change anything. If they have an audience, then debunk as appropriate with the audience in mind (which will often involve speaking past the denier, directly to the audience), but the denier is generally a lost cause.